# postgresql + how to recover the wals files

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, rhel, ambari, wal

we have postgresql version 9.x on rhel machine , postgresql is the DB of the ambari server

some of the files under folder - `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog` was deleted by mistake

from total 487 files only 5 files was deleted by mistake

example ( not the real files - only to show similar state )

```
cd /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog
[root@Ambari_server pg_xlog]# ls -ltr | more
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F1
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F2
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F3
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F4
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2020 0000000100000000000000F5
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F6
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F7
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F8
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000F9
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FA
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FB
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FC
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2020 0000000100000000000000FD
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 0000000100000000000000FE
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000000
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000001
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000002
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000003
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000004
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2020 000000010000000100000005
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000006
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000007
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000008
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 000000010000000100000009
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 00000001000000010000000A
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2020 00000001000000010000000B
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2020 00000001000000010000000C
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2020 00000001000000010000000D
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2020 00000001000000010000000E
.
.
.
.
```

for now when we try to start the postgresql as s`ystemctl status postgresql.service` , we get the error - `could not open critical system index 2662`

unfortunately we not have postgresql backup

what are the options that we can do in order to recover the wals files ( `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog` ) that are missing?

Comment: https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/how-to-recover-when-postgresql-is-missing-a-wal-file

Also, if you have untouched DB you can delete all WAL files and start from scratch by creating first WAL from existing DB.

Comment: I would not expect deleting WAL files to give a 'critical system index' error.  Are you sure WAL is the only thing deleted?

Comment: yes the only thing is the 5 wal files